# How could I deploy etherpad-lite as a cluster?

Tags: etherpad

I want to deploy the [etherpad-lite](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite) as a cluster, Would you please give me some suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a small task (yet) but if you do solve it I think the rest of the Etherpad community would really appreciate it if you could push it back to the project :)

Here is a basic howto:

1. Do simulated load testing to ensure this is something you really need to do.
2. Remove, re-engineer or Abstract Ueber DBs Caching (Using something like memcache)
3. Replace the Etherpad Room/session system with SocketIO rooms
4. Deploy sticky socket io rooms (keeps user a on pad a on same server as user b on pad a)
5. AOB
6. Do frontend testing

Simulated load testing and frontend testing comes bundled with Etherpad.  The other bits you will need to engineer yourself.

If you aren't familiar with nodejs / socket / npm / [etherpad](http://etherpad.org) then [hire someone that is](http://mclear.co.uk) :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,and I also got your email in Etherpad google groups,it's very helpful.I will feed back to Etherpad community if I solve it.